# Best way to secure REST Services develop in Play Framework for use in Android app?

Tags: web-services, security, rest, playframework-2.0

What is the Best way to secure REST Services (develop by Play Framework) for use in Android app?
Please consider the limitation of httpclient in android.
using https is enough?

Comment: What do you mean by secure?  https will prevent eavesdropping and man in the middle attacks, but it's no good for authentication.  If you want to authenticate users, then after they've logged in, assign the device a persistent token, and then put that token into a header in every request.  Make sure you generate the token in a cryptographically secure way, eg using SecureRandom.

Comment: @JamesRoper Thanks james please describe more in an answer about authentication and ssl in play framework.